# How can I repair my PHP installation?

Tags: server, apache2, php

I try to test my php installation on a ubuntu server without gui. Therefore I follow the 3rd [this howto for LAMP(!)](http://www.wpexplorer.com/locally-install-wordpress-on-ubuntu/). This includes to install php5 et al. with

```
sudo apt-get install php5 libapache2-mod-php5 php5-mcrypt
```

Then PHP is added to the directory index.

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/dir.conf
```

So that the file is:

```
<IfModule mod_dir.c>
          DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.cgi index.pl index.php index.xhtml index.htm
</IfModule>
```

I have the file `/var/www/info.php` like this:

```
<?php 
phpinfo();
?>
```

There is no output, when I try to reach the page on another machine with

```
http://hostname/info.php
```

`index.html` shows me *'It works!'*, but `/var/log/apache2/error.log` shows error:

```
[..date..] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 13057] AH00163: Apache/2.4.6 (Ubuntu) SVN/1.7.9 PHP/5.5.3-1ubuntu2.1 mod_perl/2.0.8 Perl/v5.14.2 configured -- resuming normal operations
[..date..] [core:notice] [pid 13057] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[..date..] [:error] [pid 13064] [client 192.168.x.n:59821] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '<' in /var/www/info.php on line 3
[..date..] [:error] [pid 13065] [client 192.168.x.n:59822] script '/var/www/index.php' not found or unable to stat
```

x and n are numbers, n is the ip of the client trying to access the page.

Output of cat /var/www/info.php

```
<?php
<h3 align="center">"Awesomeness has no charge" - Po the Panda</h3> <-- here is the error...ok, thx.
phpinfo();
?>
```

And

```
$ ls -la /var/www/info.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 86 Feb  1 23:33 /var/www/info.php
```

Comment: Do `cat /var/www/info.php` and show us the *full* output.

Comment: I think this is permission issue. Please provide the output of `ls -la /var/www`

Comment: Ah, even if it was to easy... The output is shown above. I thought I tried it (but it was not so): When deleting the line with the Panda everything is fine.

Comment: @StefanBollmann Did you solved the problem? If so, please write a new answer detailing how.

Comment: This is a code problem. You have put raw HTML into your `<?php ... ?>` tag, that obviously can't work. That's literally what the error tells you: Syntax error. Because the interpreter has no idea what to do with this random completely different language in there.

Comment: @Lucio: I will - in 8 hours (reputation to low)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was in info.php:

```
<?php
<h3 align="center">"Awesomeness has no charge" - Po the Panda</h3> <-- here is the    error...ok, thx.
phpinfo();
?>
```

By deleting the line with

```
<h3 align="center">"Awesomeness has no charge" - Po the Panda</h3>
```

everything is as expected. The info.php is now (as in many documentations..)

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```